# ¿como puedo ver el codigo de la libreria Tkinter en python

Tags: python, tkinter, eventos

> quisiera saber como se programan la interfaces (en crudo) en python,en este caso como esta construida Tkinter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde la versión 3.5, la documentación online de python incluye enlaces a los fuentes de cada módulo.

Así, si miras la [documentación de tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html) verás al principio de la misma un enlace que dice: Source code: [`Lib/tkinter/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) y te lleva al repositorio en GitHub donde está el código de ese módulo.

**No obstante, en el caso particular de descifrar el código de tkinter te enfrentas a una tarea titánica**, y es muy dudoso que encuentres lo que buscas, sea esto lo que sea (quizás podrías aclararlo en la pregunta). Las razones por las que tkinter es especialmente complejo son:

- El módulo python `tkinter` es en realidad lo que se llama un *wrapper*, es decir, la verdadera funcionalidad que accede al sistema de ventanas no está escrita en python, sino que python hace sólo de "envoltorio", proporcionando una sintaxis orientada a objetos y pythónica, sobre la librería que realmente hace el trabajo de crear el sistema de ventanas e interactuar con el usuario.
- Verás que lo primero que hace `tkinter` es un `import _tkinter`. Este segundo módulo es el que hace el verdadero trabajo.
- El módulo `_tkinter` está escrito en C. El código fuente forma parte del intérprete Python, y lo puedes ver en [Modules/_tkinter.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Modules/_tkinter.c)
- No se acaba aquí la cosa, porque ese módulo C es a su vez un envoltorio para proporcionar una interfaz con Python de la biblioteca tcl/tk, de la que Python depende.
- La biblioteca Tcl/Tk es una cosa muy antigua, anterior a Python. Basada en el lenguaje [Tcl](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), que era un lenguaje de scripting, un poco como python pero menos amigable en mi opinión, y que tuvo su momento de éxito en los 90 al proporcionar la biblioteca Tk que permitía crear interfaces gráficas de usuario sin tener que programar en C (que era la única forma de hacerlo entonces), sino usando Tcl. Debido al éxito de Tk, Python decidió incluirlo como mecanismo para que, él también, pudiera ofrecer un método sencillo (o más sencillo que en C) de crear interfaces gráficas de usuario.

En definitiva, Tk es una cosa heredada de los 90. Y su arquitectura es, por razones históricas, demasiado compleja. Recapitulando, pero al revés (de abajo a arriba):

- Usando C, se escribió Tcl como un lenguaje de scripting.
- Usando Tcl (y partes en C), se escribió Tk como una biblioteca para crear GUIs con Tcl.
- Usando C, se crea el módulo `_tkinter` que permite a Python comunicarse con Tcl y con Tk
- Usando Python, se crea el módulo `tkinter` que importa `_tkinter` y le da una interfaz orientada a objetos.
- Usando Python tu aplicación importa `tkinter` y crea la interfaz de usuario.

Así que cuando dices "como se programan las interfaces en crudo" ¿a qué nivel de estos te refieres? Si miras el fuente de `tkinter` no llegas aún a ver nada "en crudo". Supongo que tendrías que llegar abajo del todo, a la implementación de Tk en TCL o a la propia implementación en C de TCL. Y aún así, llegarías a un punto en que éste delega la creación de ventanas y los eventos del usuario en llamadas al propio sistema operativo (que serán diferentes en Windows que en Unix, donde se usa X-Window).

A la complejidad de todo esto, se añade la propia complejidad inherente de la programación de GUIs, sea en el lenguaje que sea, ya que se trata de una programación orientada a eventos en la que las cosas no suceden en el orden que dicta tu programa, sino en el orden que dictan los eventos de usuario (movimientos de ratón, pulsaciones de tecla...)

¡Buena suerte! :-)